# NetBeans IDE and Selenium 2.0 WebDriver // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [isTextPresent]]

Tags: junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

whenever there is "assertTextPresent" command in Selenium IDE test case then when exported to JUint 4 we have this error:

// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [isTextPresent]]

for each occurence

I know there is a workaround, but can this be automated ?

Comment: So far I was doing only workarounds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported in every binding.

So no, the only way is to do workarounds, or contribute to the Selenium project and put it into the bindings yourself :)